# New York Comic Con 2011 - SciFi & Fantasy.SE involvement

Tags: discussion

[New York Comic Con](http://www.newyorkcomiccon.com/) is approaching soon (October 13-16) and I would like for this site to have a presence of some sort. Here's what I tentatively propose:

- Up to **20 users** from SciFi.SE can attend with weekend passes, courtesy of Stack Exchange
- all users in attendance will get a Stack Exchange NYCC swag package (which would possibly include the to-be-designed Sci Fi.SE t-shirt, a Stack Exchange tote bag, a Stack Exchange lanyard, etc.) to hopefully use at the con and, also, your day-to-day existence
- all users (possibly only 21+ users) may be invited to a NYCC Stack Exchange party held at a bar near the Javits Center, with free drinks and/or food for a TBD period of time
- users involved with the blog would are encouraged to liveblog the event; if the blog gets up and running before the con, I will try to get those users press passes

That's what I have in mind. If there's a big gap in my thinking, please fill it with your knowledge! AKA, leave a comment. In the future I could see Stack Exchange having an actual booth presence, but that's cutting it a little close for October. Starting small. But before we discuss the bullet points in detail, I really just want to know:

**Are any of you already going to New York Comic Con/would you go if Stack Exchange bought your ticket?**

If the answer is yes, please e-mail me at **brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com** with the title **NYCC 2011 - SciFi & Fantasy.SE involvement**:

1. Your name
2. Your address
3. What days you wish to attend
4. If you wish to write content for the blog

Thanks!

Comment: If this gets off the ground, I'd be happy to go. Gotta have some kind of mod presence, and I live the closest to it. :)

Comment: I wish i could go... I live in Missouri.

Comment: Added email information to the post. If you wish to attend, email me that information and we will start the process of getting your tickets mailed to you. Yeah!

Comment: Does this include a plane ticket to New York? ;)