# What do you think of these site promotion ideas?

Tags: discussion

I'm kinda [borrowing this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/what-do-you-think-of-these-site-promotion-ideas) idea and post-structure from my CHAOS-mate Lauren, but she won't mind if *we don't tell her* [/joking]. As most of you know, I've been working on promoting SF&F for the past couple of months, and I'd love to have some help brainstorming. Here's a list of some things I've been doing, where I need your input, and things I'd like to try out:

- **Sponsoring giveaways and contests on blogs:** This seems to be working well over on [DIY](http://www.younghouselove.com/2011/08/fab-freebie-its-a-one-derful-life/), [Fitness](http://www.crankyfitness.com/2011/08/fitbit-giveaway.html), [English](http://preciseedit.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/wordsmith-contest/) and [Photography](http://www.photographyblogger.net/feisol-carbon-fiber-tripod-giveaway/), but I've not had a lot of luck with applying this to our site. And it's not for a lack of stuff to give away, cause Sci-Fi and Fantasy has stuff out the wazoo; it's more a lack of non-corporate-owned sites that will pay attention to us, as well as blogs that actually do giveaways. **What blogs, big and small, do you read? Do they do giveaways?**
- **Ad space:** I am in talks with New York Comic Con about getting adspace in their newsletter. I'd love to get an ad on other big Sci-Fi sites. This goes hand-in-hand with the previous point, so the blogs you suggest for that one I can also approach about advertising. **So again, what sites, big and small, do you read?**
- **Going to conferences:** If anyone is in the New York area and interested in going to New York Comic Con ([see the Meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/725/new-york-comic-con-2011-scifi-fantasy-se-involvement)), we have a limited amount of 3 day passes and would love to get you in. If you are interested in that, please email me at brett[at]stackexchange[dot]com. We can provide you with Stack swag to wear and hand out. That being said, **are there any other conferences that you are planning to attend?** This most likely falls more towards the Community Team than CHAOS, but I'd like to know so I can reach out to them for advertising.
- **Sponsoring meetups and other events:** We are sponsoring the event collective Newmindspace's [NYC Lightsaber Battle](http://www.newmindspace.com/lightsaber-battle-nyc) by providing them with [Jedi robes](http://www.facebook.com/Newmindspace?sk=app_190322544333196). If you are in the New York City area, you should come out! Are there any **other type of events that I should look into sponsoring**? Do you run an event/meetup that is crazy successful or has a lot of attendees?

These are just some ideas we've been tossing around at the office. Does anyone have thoughts about anything else we should try? I want to get this site a ton of new eyeballs and great, longterm users. Let's make it happen!

Comment: I read engadget and io9.  Engadget does giveaways, I don't think io9 does.

Comment: I read/watch the escapist and Penny Arcade. They might do giveaways. Or might be interested in cross advertisement. I don't know if this would be more for videogames.se, though

Comment: surely a few of the zillions of scifi related blogs must be suitable? Maybe once you get outside the corporate big blog mainstream?

Comment: @JeffAtwood I'm trying to find out what blogs our users read so I can narrow it down from zillions to a handful that I can approach.

Comment: I don't know how they work as for advertising, but there is a [slashdot scifi tag](http://slashdot.org/index2.pl?fhfilter=scifi), there is also others tags, like games or math that could link to others stack-exchange sites.

Comment: I'm sure we could get a few movies/ books/ tickets fairly easily for give aways. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

As for events that you may be interested to sponsoring and/or sending peoples to, there is the [Fantasia International Film Festival.](http://www.fantasiafest.com/2011/en/info/about.php) here in Montreal. Of course the 2011 edition is past, but you may want to look at this for 2012.